# Regression not possible for same y value

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, linear-regression, data-science

I want to run a regression analysis on below data, here `x1` and `x2` produce `y` value. But in that case, `y` value is fixed in all time. So regression will not happen. But why? Need explanation.

[image: see image here]

Comment: question is better asked in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Regression answers the question, "What is the relationship between changes in Y and changes in X1 and X2?" - in this data set, because Y is constant there is no such relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Your training set shows that the coefficients are all ~0 and the constant is 5. There's no more information in that dataset, you don't need regression to show that.

You did not specify what kind of regression you are running. Depending on the type of regression you are using, you will need the matrices to be [invertible and not be related linearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)).

It seems to work using normal equation (with expected results):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
input = np.array([
    [2,3,5],
    [1,2,5],
    [4,2,5],
    [1,7,5],
    [1,9,5]
])
m = len(input)
X = np.array([np.ones(m), input[:, 0],input[:, 1]]).T # Add Constant to X
y = np.array(input[:, 2]).reshape(-1, 1) # Get the dependant values
betaHat = np.linalg.solve(X.T.dot(X), X.T.dot(y)) # Calculate coefficients
print(betaHat) # Show Constant and coefficients (in that order)
[[  5.00000000e+00]
[  5.29208238e-16]
[  4.32685981e-17]]
```